# Spanish calendar on mobile devices using input="date"

Tags: html, datepicker

I'm just wondering if it is possible to have a Spanish version of the calendar that displays when using the native datepicker .

Thank you!

Comment: I would think that is entirely dependent on which browser/rendering engine implementation it is running on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a non-Spanish-language device, no. Ideally you would use `<input type="date" lang="es">` but I suspect you will find that does not work.